# Strikeout multiple lines and collumns with a checkbox

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Is there some sort of conditional formating I could use to do this?

I would like the checkbox in col A to trigger strikeout in col B,C,D but stop before the next name in column B.

I am able to set the checkbox to strikeout multiple lines with conditional formatting, but with the number of lines changing with every name, this is not a viable option.

I used =$A1=TRUE for the range I want strikeout, but this would mean I need to apply this everytime I have a different number of rows with a new range?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Done! Thank you for the guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with this formula. Try it and let me know:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,XMATCH("*",$B$1:$B1,2,-1))
```

It looks up the previous non empty cell in B and with INDEX it checks the value of column A:

[image]

Comment: @Sheetster see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)